# Removing duplicates based on repeated column indices Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that has rows with repeated values in sequences.

For example:

```
df_raw

0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14....
220    450    451    456    470    224    220    223    221    340    224    220    223    221    340.....
234    333    453    460    551    226    212    115    117    315    226    212    115    117    315.....
```

As you see the columns `0-6` are **unique** in this example and then we have repeated sequences `[220    223    221    340    224]` for `row 1` from columns `6-10` and then again from `11-14`.

This pattern is the same for `row 2`.

I'd like to **remove** the repeated sequences for each row of my dataframe (more than just 2) for an output like this:

```
df_clean

0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9.....
220    450    451    456    470    224    220    223    221    340.....
234    333    453    460    551    226    212    115    117    315.....
```

I trail with `......` because the columns are long and have multiple repeatitions for each row. I also cannot assume that each row has the exact same amount of repeated sequences nor that each sequence starts at the exact same index or ends at the same index.

Is there an easy way to do this with `pandas` or even a numpy array?

Comment: Did you check `pandas` duplicates API? [Here is the link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Comment: Can you post a dataframe that can be easily pasted into someone else's code (i.e. in the form `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`?  Then it will be easier for someone to solve.  It's okay if the sample dataframe is much simpler and shorter than the real thing.

Comment: `df.T.drop_duplicates().T` did you want this? just checking. If not can you please explain a little more. Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what counts as a "repeated sequence"?  It sounds like they don't need to match across all rows.  What is the minimum length for a repetition?  Is two sequential numbers in the same row enough to drop?  What should happen if there's a repeating sequence in one row but not in the next - what happens when the repeated values get dropped?

Comment: Well some numbers in each row can be repeated without being in a sequence (like zeroes side-by-side or any floats) so I cannot drop_duplicates that easily. Also, a repeat sequence is any set of numbers the same length that repeat together. In my current dataframe they seem to repeat **after** the 5th index (column 6) every 5 indices (6-10, 11-14, etc...) - and they only repeat a sequence once. Ie: `row 1` repeats columns `6-10` from `11-14` only once in the row. After that, each 10 values